# Phonegap plugin barcodescanner crashes on iOs

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, intel-xdk

For a project I am working on there has to be a way to scan QR-Codes. I've got this one from the [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner). As is, it works well on Android, never had any problems.

But on iOs it will crash as is. You will get a request to use the camera, and then the app crashes. The way I found around this is to remove the options part of it, then it works.

This looks like a bit of a strange way to solve it. **Question: is there a better way to solve this?**

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  },
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  },
  {
      "preferFrontCamera" : true, // iOS and Android
      "showFlipCameraButton" : true, // iOS and Android
      "prompt" : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // supported on Android only
      "formats" : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      "orientation" : "landscape" // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
  }
);
```

Using: Windows 10, Intel XDK v3619, Cordova CLI 6.2.0 and phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 4.1.0

Comment: Sorry for proposing a dumb solution but it worked for me... For me the crash happened on android and what I did is: I removed the android platform (cordova plartform rm android), defined the latest Cordova CLI for compilation (currently 6.4.0). Actually the build failed so I rolled back to the previous CLI that worked for me (6.1.1) and re-added the android platform (cordova platform add android). Then it miracuosly started to work and stopped crashing. Try with platform "ios". Could work for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I have also had crash issues with cordova-plugin-barcodescanner on IOS 10 via Phonegap Build.

Solved now after hours of trying, I had to add the **cordova-plugin-camera** first and then the **cordova-plugin-barcodescanner**.

Here's the relevant extract my working config.xml:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data: gap:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.1">
<variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="My App would like to access your camera, to take photos of your documents." />
</plugin>

<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-barcodescanner">
<variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="abc123" />
</plugin>
```

On both Android6 and IOS10 the example of GitHub is now working well: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner